# Tradução de URLs como /help

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tradução, internacionalização

Creio que deveria haver um redirecionamento de /ajuda para o /help, o que acham? Como fica a questão da tradução no que diz respeito às URLs?

Comment: Acho que as URLs não podem ser modificadas/traduzidas.

Comment: Acabei perguntando algo aparecida, justamente porque, para aquelas pessoas que digitam o URL "à mão" (deve ter ok, uns dez ou vinte no mundo? :P), pode ser difícil de achar páginas pois são todos em inglês. Acho uma boa idea suportar os dois idiomas, o segundo sendo 'redirected' à primeira. Esse poderia ser um precidente para outros sites do SO em outros idiomas (quando surgem)